# How can I minimize path between two points on contour?

Tags: python, contour, path-finding

how can I minimize path between two points on contour? at the end, the shortest path should also be perpendicular to all the contour lines.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fY6o.jpg)]

can somebody provide me insight on how to approach this problem or point me in the right direction?

I have not been able to think how to approach this problem.

Comment: The shortest path is a straight line. That can’t also be perpendicular to all contours. Define what you want better.

Comment: The shortest path, in a more general sense, is not necessarily a straight line, if it is weighted by some term. In the given case, I guess OP means the path of overall least energy. I agree they should pose their question more clearly though.

Comment: Looking at the linked image and the red-dotted path the OP may mean “the path between two minima with the least free-energy barrier”, but “shortest path” that isn’t.

Comment: @GauravParajuli The following question seems to be related, and the answers might give you some hints on where to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613106/finding-least-energy-path-across-an-image